# WPF application on Citrix

Tags: wpf, citrix

I'm trying to use a WPF application on our Citrix server, and made a really simple window with a button and a textbox. When running the application, noting but the application name on top of the window is shown. Is it not possible to use WPF on Citrix, or is our Citrix server too old?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It should be [possible](http://community.citrix.com/display/ocb/2007/05/04/Citrix+WPF+support) to use WPF on Citrix starting with PS 4.5 Feature pack 1.

Is your version older than this?

Comment: Our problem was this: http://forums.citrix.com/thread.jspa?threadID=102299&tstart=-2 with the following hotfix: http://forums.citrix.com/thread.jspa?threadID=102299&tstart=-2